# How to determine secured ipv6 addr and temporary ipv6 addr? Is it secure to use secured ipv6 addr for DDNS and internet aceess?

Tags: ipv6, ddns

I'm setting a linux kernel router, how to determine secured ipv6 addr and temporary ipv6 addr?When I run ifconfig on macOS, it will output like this:

```
inet6 fe80::0000:0000:0000:3e7d%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x8
inet6 2409:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ef95 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured   
inet6 2409:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:8ab8 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary
```

But the output on the router is like this:

```
inet6 addr: 2409:8a50:ae02:4d23:6891:614f:66a1:504b/64 Scope:Global
inet6 addr: 2409:8a50:ae02:4d23:403c:5ee7:98eb:8474/64 Scope:Global
inet6 addr: fe80::403c:5ee7:98eb:8474/10 Scope:Link
```

Ubuntu 18.04 output:

```
inet6 2409:8a50:ae2c:2cc0:95c4:27f6:5dba:72cf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 2409:8a50:ae2c:2cc0:361:36e3:6d02:314d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 fe80::9e5:6b35:11c4:5e7c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

And I want use a simple script to update DDNS, should I use secured ipv6 addr or temporary ipv6 addr?

Comment: Please do not obfuscate IP addresses, provide real ones or use the documentation prefix. I find it exceedingly unlikely that your prefix + generated address would be in 2409::/64. Way too many zeros.

Comment: @JohnMahowald And we have a [reference](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963) you can point people to.

Comment: @JohnMahowald I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, avoid temporary addresses in DNS, they change more often. However, pick whatever address you like, such as adding a static address. Should have an entire /64 to use.

Secure in a macOS IPv6 address context means [RFC 3972 (Cryptographically Generated Addresses)](https://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2016/09/disabling-secured-ipv6-addresses-is-macos-10-12-sierra/). I do not know enough about the [XNU network stack](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/xnu-4903.221.2/bsd/netinet6/in6_var.h#L756) to verify this, but seems plausible.